# Magento Code Migration Tool - Installation issue

Tags: magento, cmd, failed-installation, magento-2.0, code-migration

i'm currently following the steps in

> https://github.com/magento/code-migration

to install the Code Migration Tool (not data migrate) to my localhost.

i am facing a problem at the

**`Installation step`**

When i run `composer install`,

1. it requires me username and password, 
   saying
   `Authentication required (repo.magento.com)` ,

and i tried a few attemps, it just says

`Invalid credential for https://repo.magento.com/packages.json, aborting.`

i have done little research about the username and password on internet..

> https://community.magento.com/t5/Just-Ask-Alan/Invalid-credentials-for-https-repo-magento-com-packages-json/m-p/23820#M127

They suggested to get the private key and public key from my magento marketplace account, i did that but it doesn't work.

---

2. Also, the cmd doesn't allow me to type anything at the password.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks >.<

Comment: The password that you type is not visible to you so continue typing and see if it works.

Comment: i see, thanks for answering the issue in number 2. 
Then what about number 1? do u have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can use migration tool from UberTheme for Magento2

it is very much user friendly

REF : https://github.com/ubertheme/module-ubdatamigration/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the suggestion, but right now i need a _**code** migration tool_ not _data migration tool_.

Comment: hi i have encounter a new problem, feel free to have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319940/magento-2-redirecting-to-payment-gateway-error